# how to change the color of statusbar in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Can Anybody tell me how the change the color of this statusbar into other colors. As you can see in the following image it's a dark color and the time, battery, network details also shown in dark. so that's making them invisible.
I either want to change the color dynamically like when the background color becomes dark the text color of the system widgets ( time , battery, network) becomes white and when color is light those becomes dark.

or If I have to hardcode the color each time. where should I do it? Any solution will be appreciable.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to achieve this in flutter built in functions.
in `MaterialApp` go inside `theme`
create `AppBarTheme` and give the property `brightenss: Brightness.dark or Brightness.light` based on your requirement. If your status bar color is dark then give `Brightness.dark` it will make icons and text in white color and vice versa for light background.

Answer (score 0):

this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor

```
import 'package:flutter_statusbarcolor/flutter_statusbarcolor.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.white);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the package only solution for it?

Comment: You can read this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html

Comment: but i think flutter_statusbarcolor is better.

Comment: The package is discontinued. It's not working. On the official api.flutter.dev documentation they have shown implementation in build method. What if we have multiple pages. Do we need to implement that in every screen. Is there anyway that we can mention it in main.dart and will be applied in all the app without importing the certain code in every view or every file?